# Document.getElementById(update[0]) is null

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm getting this error when submitting, it does properly send but the user is not notified that it sent.

document.getElementById(update[0]) is null

```
<script language="javascript">

function createRequestObject() {

var ro;
var browser = navigator.appName;
if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
    ro = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}else{
    ro = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
return ro;
}

var http = createRequestObject();

function sendemail() {
var msg = document.contactform.msg.value;
var name = document.contactform.name.value;
var email = document.contactform.email.value;
var subject = document.contactform.subject.value;
document.contactform.send.disabled=true; 
document.contactform.send.value='Sending....';

http.open('get', 'contact.php?msg='+msg+'&name='+name+'&subject='+subject+'&email='+email+'&action=send');
http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
http.send(null);
}

function handleResponse() {
if(http.readyState == 4){
    var response = http.responseText;
    var update = new Array();

    if(response.indexOf('|') != -1) {
        update = response.split('|');
        document.getElementById(update[0]).innerHTML = update[1];

    }
}
}
</script>
```

contact.php

```
if(!isset($_GET['action']))
{
die("You must not access this page directly!"); 
}

$name = trim($_GET['name']); //The senders name
$email = trim($_GET['email']); //The senders email address
$subject = trim($_GET['subject']); //The senders subject
$message = trim($_GET['msg']); //The senders message

mail($to,$subject,$message,"From: ".$email."");
echo 'response|Thank you '.$name.', 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

*Edit, for updated question:* [Your site appears to work](http://www.megabytemedia.net/test/contacts.html) for me now, be sure to clear your cache with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> if you're still having issues.

Your `if()` check is a little off, this:

```
if(response.indexOf('|' != -1)) {
```

should be:

```
if(response.indexOf('|') != -1) {
```

currently you're getting a false positive, and the code inside that `if` shouldn't even be executing...but they are :)

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of `update` right before your `getElementById` line? Use `console.log` or equivalent to see if the array includes what you expect.

Comment: Also, yes, Nick Craver noticed a syntax error -- that will need to be fixed first for sure! :)

Answer (score 0):

This means that whatever you're returning in the responseText, is not what you're wanting.

If you're returning

"updatePanel|my message"

you need something on your page like this:

```
<div id="updatePanel">your message will go here</div>
```

So check your return value by alerting or inspecting the responseText. Firebug will help you.

Comment: echo 'response|Thank you '.$name.', your email has been sent.'; //now lets update the "response" div on the contact.html page. The response| tell's the javascript which div to update.
?> and on my page I have
    <div id="response"</div>

Comment: @Dustin - Is your `<div>` *exactly* like that? It's missing a closing `>` on the tag if so.

Comment: <div id="response"></div> sorry

Comment: @Dustin - Is that your *entire* response, or is the rest of the page rendering as well?  Try `alert(response)`, what are you seeing?

Comment: @Dustin - The response I'm getting is: `<br /><b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in <b>/home/megabyte/public_html/test/contact.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />`, so you're not getting a valid response back because of a PHP error.

Comment: @Dustin - It's fixed now, not sure what you did...the `<div>` is being populated with the message, but it has ` display: none;` style rule on it you need to remove, looks like your only issue was the syntax error I posted in my answer :)

Comment: not getting any errors, I removed the display rule, and still not getting it to display ?

Comment: @Dustin - Ctrl+F5 to completely clear your cache, it's working here.